# Python2 and Python3 both in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, anaconda

I used Anaconda for python.

python2 is installed in
   `D:\Python\Anaconda2`

python3 is installed in
   `D:\Python\Anaconda3`

python3 is the default.

created two environmental variables with name: `python2` and `python2` and selected respective `python.exe` from different folder respectively.

my setup.py supports only python2.

when i run command from cmd `python setup.py install` it says it does not support.
If I rename `D:\Python\Anaconda2\python.exe` to `D:\Python\Anaconda2\python2.exe` and change the environment path file accordingly it works. But I dnt want to change the file name (as it may break other apps, like conda says unable to create process, etc).

Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit.
setup.py location:
`E:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio1251\cplex\python\x64_win64`

1. How to overcome this? Want `python2 setup.py install` for python2 compiler and `python3 setup.py install` for python3 compiler, without renaming.
2. How to install setup.py by running  `D:\Python\Anaconda2\python.exe`?

Comment: Renaming python.exe is a bad idea, but you can create a symbolic link using an administrator command prompt, e.g. `mklink python2.exe python.exe`. Do the same for Python 3, and add both directories to `PATH`, with the preferred python.exe directory listed first.

Comment: Yes, that's a horrible idea.When I tried to add it to env var, it's taking as `python.exe` only

Comment: Yes, that's a horrible idea. What to change in env path/ var?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this directly answers your question,but anaconda manages environments for you. [Reference](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html)

You should be able to type into your Anaconda prompt to create your environment:

```
conda create --name pyenv python=2.7
```

and then list your environments:

```
conda info --envs
```

and lastly activate your environment python 2 or python 3 environments:

```
activate pyenv
```

These separate environments with their own versions of python are saved in the anaconda folder under the envs folder

> /Anaconda3/envs/pyenv/python

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how you can use both python2 and python3 in windows 10**

- Install python2 from here https://www.python.org/downloads/
- Install python3 from here https://www.python.org/downloads/

Enter windows keys and type "Edit the system environment variables"

- Click on Path and enter Edit button.
  [image]
- Add path to both version of python. (Important) Here i have listed python3 and python2 in order because i want to see version 2 by python --version and version3 by python3 --version.
  [image]
- Go to C:\python310 in windows (or whatever the name is for python3) and update executable file to python3 instead of python.
  [image]

Save and exit.

Now,

- python --version // python 2
- python3 --version // python 3

If you want it otherwise, update executable file of python2 to python2 instead of python. And update PATH variables to list python2 and python3 in order.